# Injecting data into jQuery datatable instead of directly to DOM

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables

I have a situation where I'm injecting data from jQuery-AJAX response directly into the DOM like this:

```
.done(function(data) {
    StopLoading();
    var brands = $('<table />').append(data).find('#tableProducts').html();
    $('#tableProducts').html(brands);
    var dbtb = $('<table />').append(data).find('#datatable-responsive').html();
    $('#datatable-responsive').html(dbtb);

    $('#datatable-responsive').dataTable({

      "bDestroy": true
    });
    var header = $('<div />').append(data).find('.bs-glyphicons').html();
    $('.bs-glyphicons').html(header);
    $('#tableProducts thead, #header').fadeIn("slow");
    $('#emptyText').hide();
}
})
```

This is the tricky part:

```
 var brands = $('<table />').append(data).find('#tableProducts').html();
 $('#tableProducts').html(brands);
 var dbtb = $('<table />').append(data).find('#datatable-responsive').html();
 $('#datatable-responsive').html(dbtb);

 $('#datatable-responsive').dataTable({

   "bDestroy": true
 });
```

Note that I fetch the table from the data object and then inject it into the browser's DOM. After that I destroy and re-create the datatable...

What I'd like to change here is that I don't inject directly all items into the DOM directly, but rather pass it to the datatable so that the datatable can Inject lets say only 10-100 first items that it finds and splits them into pages as it does...

How can I do this? Knowing that the data that I receive in DATA object is HTML, and Datatable in jQuery receives only JSON format, this is what causes me the problem.

So the questions are:

1. Can I pass the HTML data to jQuery datatable and let it inject only 100 items into the table (instead of 1000-2000 as it does right now)
2. If #1 is not doable, I could return JSON form the server and then inject it into the DT.
3. If #2 is doable, How could I convert a list, type of TestData like following:

   ```
   public class TestData
   {
       public string StoreName { get; set; }
       public string Sales { get; set; }
       public string Address { get; set; }
       public string City { get; set; }
   }
   ```

To a JSON format which is acceptable for jQuery datatable?

Comment: Seems like you are trying to manually work around the powerful built in features of datatable plugin that will do all that you describe already when configured properly

Comment: @charlietfl You got a very good point! But is there any way to pass the data into datatable directly so that I can avoid injecting 1000-2500 items to DOM , this is my main goal here... Since datatable already has implemented paging, i'd just like to combine it with what I have already...

Comment: P.S. I'm trying to, as well , to figure out how to properly set it up so that my browser web page doesn't freezes when the data is injected into DOM

Comment: Yes, you can pass data in numerous ways including simply pointing to a url. Go through the examples on docs site

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you have thousand plus records your browser will freeze because of the loop to make the html and display the records on client. To avoid this problem there are number of solutions and as you are using jquery data table plugin you should use it's server side paging and here the links that can help you.

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/28388/server-side-pagination-using-data-table

These links are really usefull for you.

https://www.codeproject.com/kb/aspnet/jquery-datatables-mvc.aspx

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCouA3tuA3o